# Normalise ID where 2 FK exist in row

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a view to normalise "Sports Fixtures", however I have the ID of both the home team and the away team in a row in the fixtures table. When trying to normalise these, how can I get the team name of the relevant team?

```
select cast(`f`.`datetime` as date) AS `date`
     , cast(`f`.`datetime` as time) AS `time`
     , (select `t`.`name` 
        from (`fixturef_testing`.`teams` `t` 
        join `fixturef_testing`.`fixtures` `f` 
          on((`f`.`hometeamid` = `t`.`id`))) 
        where (`t`.`id` = `f`.`hometeamid`)) AS `hometeam`
     , (select `t`.`name` 
        from (`fixturef_testing`.`teams` `t` 
        join `fixturef_testing`.`fixtures` `f` 
          on((`f`.`awayteamid` = `t`.`id`))) 
        where (`t`.`id` = `f`.`awayteamid`)) AS `awayteam`
     , `u`.`name` AS `referee`,`c`.`name` AS `competition` 
from ((`fixturef_testing`.`fixtures` `f` 
left join `fixturef_testing`.`users` `u` 
  on((`u`.`id` = `f`.`refereeid`))) 
left join `fixturef_testing`.`competition` `c` 
  on((`c`.`id` = `f`.`competitionid`))) 
where (`f`.`active` = 1)
```

Fixtures has hometeamid and awayteamid
Teams has id and name

I have tried a a subquery but it returns multiple results.

Any help/advise is appreciated.

[Teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng9Oo.png)
[Fixtures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoP0u.png)

Comment: I think you just need to join to teams  twice, once for hometeam and once for away team.

Comment: The table name in the join needs to be unique - I have tried that too. (If I only join to that table once, it will always give me the home team name (or the field I have joined with - e.g. join on f.hometeamid = t.id)

Comment: you need to alias the table  once as HomeTeam HT, the other as AwayTeam AT or similar

Comment: And you're not trying to "Normalize them" you're trying to denormalize them.. You want the Names of each ID, not the ID's themselves.  At this point post sample data and expected results to help clairify your question.  and state the problem/question this query is attempting to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join to teams twice, once for home team, once for away.

Think of it this way: for each foreign key you have to the same table, you need another join.

Though I'm not sure why you have the multiple joins to fixturef_testing one for user and one for completion...

Also, I'm not a fan of putting everything in the back ticks.  I'd rather only use that when I have a reserved/keyword to make it more readable.

```
SELECT cast(f.`datetime` as date) AS `date`
     , cast(f.`datetime` as time) AS `time`
     , HT.Name hometeam
     , AT.Name awayteam
     , u.name AS referee
     , c.name AS competition
FROM fixturef_testing.fixtures f
--Are the next 2 joins really needed?--
LEFT JOIN  fixturef_testing.users u 
  on u.id = f.refereeid
LEFT JOIN  fixturef_testing.competition c 
  on c.id = f.competitionid
--Not sure what the above joins are for...
--Get the table Teams record for the home team
LEFT JOIN Teams HT  
 on HT.ID = f.hometeamID 
--Get the table Teams record for the away team
LEFT JOIN Teams AT
 on AT.ID = f.awayTeamID
WHERE f.active = 1
```